# Let a, b, and c be integers. If (a · b) | c, then a | c.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove:
Let a, b, and c be integers. If (a · b) | c, then a | c.
Suppose a, b, c are integers with
(a · b) | c. Then c = (_____) · (a · b) for some integer k, so c = (____)a, so a | c.

I was able to solve:
Give a direct proof:
Let a, b, and c be integers. If a | b and a | c, then a | (b · c).
Remember that you must use the definition of | in your proof.
Suppose a, b, and c are integers and a | b and a | c. By the definition of |, b = ak1 and c = (k2a)for some integers k1 and k2. Therefore, b · c = (k1k2a^2) = ((k1k2a)a), and (ak1k2)is an integer, so a | b · c.

I am just having some problems with the question stated above.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $ab\mid c$, then by definition $(ab)k=c$ for some integer $k$. Thus $a(bk)=c$ by associativity. Hence, $a\mid c$.